# Elements disposition themselves as I re-size my browser

Tags: css, html

I realise this question has been asked multiple times, however all times are irrelevant to my problem. All elements I have used 'position:absolute' on move across the screen as I re-size the browser, meaning all people with a different browser to the one i have designed will see this. It is devastating! I have to use absolute positioning, it lets me stack an image on top of another one which is essential in my site. So how can I fix this and make all elements behave the same? Is there a way to force the browser to be 1366 x 768 (my browser size) as this is the size that the site looks fine on? Thank you very much if you help me.

**HTML and CSS**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <title>Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css">
 /*<![CDATA[*/



<!-- 
body  {
font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #cdcdff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
overflow-x: auto; /* for horizontal scrolling*/
overflow-y: auto; /* for vertical scrolling */
}


.twoColFixLtHdr #container {
width: 1024px;
background: #f2f2ff;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
height: 1050px;
} 

.twoColFixLtHdr #header {
background: #DDDDDD;
width: 1024px;
height: 200px;
} 

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #sidebar1 #serieshyp #hyp {
margin-top: 3%;
visibility: visible;
z-index: 10000;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #sidebar1 #ptext {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 12px;
width: 80%;
line-height: 125%;
margin-left: 8%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #second-pic {
width: 115px;
height: 170px;
margin-left: 6%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #header #home1 {
width: 110px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
right: 617px;
z-index: 200;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #sidebar1 #serieshyp {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 5%;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Calibri;
color: #000;
text-transform: none;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 9%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #header #about1 {
height: 30px;
width: 110px;
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
right: 507px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #header #information1 {
height: 30px;
width: 110px;
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
right: 397px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #header #contact1 {
height: 30px;
width: 110px;
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
right: 287px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #header #usefullinks1 {
height: 30px;
width: 110px;
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
right: 177px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 {
float: left;
width: 25%;
background: #f2f2ff;
padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #sidebar1 #serieshyp #hyp2 {
margin-top: 3%;
margin-bottom: 6%;
color: #000;
}

     #bolden    {
margin-top: 4%;
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bolder;
margin-left: 8%;
}

    h1 {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bolder;
   }
.twoColFixLtHdr #mainContent {
margin: 0 0 0 250px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #footer {
padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
background:#DDDDDD;
position: absolute;
width: 1024px;
height: 100px;
top: 1020px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #yourweddingcerelogo {
width: 650px;
height: 49px;
position: absolute;
top: 213px;
left: 503px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondlogo {
height: 49px;
width: 650px;
margin-bottom: 4%;
position: absolute;
left: 503px;
top: 650px;
margin-top: 1%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #band {
position: absolute;
width: 130px;
visibility: visible;
left: 27
.%;
top: 200px;
left: 400px;
height: 122
  ..5%;
height: 1050px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #contenttext {
margin-left: 13.5%;
margin-top: 10%;
width: 80%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #footer p {
margin: 0; 
padding: 10px 0; 
}

.fltrt { 
float: right;
margin-left: 8px;
}

.fltlft {
float: left;
margin-right: 8px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext {
margin-left: 10%;
margin-top: 10%;
width: 60%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #secondtext2 {
width: 170px;
position: absolute;
right: 43
.%;
font-family: Calibri;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
right: 525px;
top: 722px;
}

  w      {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: italic;
line-height: 1.6;
font-weight: bold;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #2ndcoltext2 {
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
width: 14.2%;
right: 80%;
top: 87.7%;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #nekcoltxt {
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
width: 175px;
top: 720px;
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #nekcolmaintxt {
height: 140px;
width: 320px;
position: absolute;
left: 833px;
top: 820px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #secondtext3 {
width: 280px;
margin-left: 3.5%;
margin-top: 0%;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
right: 538px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #secondarytext #nekcolpic {
position: absolute;
height: 95px;
width: 130px;
right: 385px;
clear: both;
top: 723px;
}

.twoColFixLtHdr #container #mainContent #contenttext c {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
}

.clearfloat {
clear:both;
height:0;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 0px;
}

p {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
}

--> 
/*]]>*/
</style><!--[if IE 5]>
<style type="text/css"> 

.twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 { width: 230px; }
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> 

.twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 { padding-top: 30px; }
.twoColFixLtHdr #mainContent { zoom: 1; }

</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

   <!-- Main Class Plan -->

  <body class="twoColFixLtHdr">

   <div id="container">

    <div id="header">

        <!--img containing necc header elements -->


        <img height="100%" src="BaseImages/MainHeader.png" width="100%" />


        <div id="home1">

        <!-- hyperlinks following -->

        <a href="HomePage.html">

        <img height="100%" src="BaseImages/1%20Home%20button.png" width="100%" />

        </a>

</div>

<div id="about1">

    <a href="AboutBriony.html">    

    <img height="100%"

    src="BaseImages/2%20about%20briony%20button.png"

    width="100%" />

    </a>

</div>

<div id="information1">

    <a href="Information.html">

    <img height="100%"

    src="BaseImages/3%20Information%20button.png"

    width="100%" />

    </a>

    </div>

<div id="contact1">

    <a href="ContactDetails.html">

    <img height="100%"

    src="BaseImages/4%20contact%20button.png"

    width="100%" />

    </a>

</div>

<div id="usefullinks1">

    <a href="UsefulLinks.html">    

  <img height="100%"

    src="BaseImages/usefullinks1.png"

    width="100%" />

    </a>

</div>

<!-- end hyperlinks -->

   </div>

    <!-- end #header -->

   <div id="sidebar1">

     <img height="30%"

    src="BaseImages/label%201%20ceremonies.png"

    width="100%" />

        <div id="serieshyp">

   <!--var of hyperlinks -->

            <div id="hyp">

                <a href="HomePage.html"

                style="text-decoration:none">

                Wedding Ceremonies

                </a>

     </div>

            <div id="hyp">

              <a href="SameSexWeddingCeremonies.html"

                style="text-decoration:none">

                Same-Sex Commitment Ceromonies

              </a>

    </div>

            <div id="hyp">

                <a href="RenewalofVows.html"

                style="text-decoration:none">

                Renewal of Vows

                </a>

   </div>

            <div id="hyp">

                <a href="CeremonyOptions.html"

                style="text-decoration:none">

                Ceremony Options

                </a>

  </div>

            <div id="hyp2">

                <a href="FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html"

                style="text-decoration:none">

                Frequently Asked Questions

                </a>

            <br />

          </div>

</div>

  <!-- hyp end-->

        <img height="30%"

        src="BaseImages/label%20extras%20and%20ideas.png"

        width="100%" />

<!--uniform label -->

<div id="bolden">

    Choosing the Right Celebrant

</div>

<div id="ptext">

    When choosing your Celebrant,  it’s not all about the money.
    it will help if you consider the personality you are looking for, not just the fee.
    Choosing a celebrant whose personal style fits in well with the type of ceremony you have in mind       is far more important than finding the cheapest price.
    The right celebrant can have a hugely positive impact on your wedding
    and help make your day go smoothly and happily.  

</div>

<div id="bolden">

    Poetry

</div>

<div id="ptext">

    I have a wide variety of poetry and readings for you to choose from
    or you can use special verses which have special meaning to you both.
    These can be seamlessly included in your marriage ceremony and often
    are a real highlight.
    You might like to consider having friends and family members
    read one or two poems for you on the day, or I can do it for you.
    It’s completely up to you.

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />  <!--find sub for br breaks -->
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

</div>

<!-- end #sidebar1 -->

</div>

<div id="mainContent">

    <div id="yourweddingcerelogo">

        <img height="100%"

        src="BaseImages/page%201%20label%20your%20wedding%20ceremony.png"

        width="100%" />

    </div>

    <div id="band">

    <!-- change according to page -->

    <img height="100%"

    src="BaseImages/ElongatedFlower3.png"

    width="100%" />

    </div>

    <div id="contenttext">

          <h1>

           A Ceremony Designed Especially for You

          </h1>

           <p>

           I believe that you should have exactly what you want on your special day.

           </p>

            <c>

            I understand how much time and effort goes into planning your dream wedding,
            so I workwith you to ensure your special day is exactly how you want it.
            It means the world to me to help you find the perfect verse,
            write the most meaningful vows and put together
            a service you will remember for the rest of your lives.

            <br />

            </c>

            <p>

            You’re certain to have wonderful ideas and plans for how you would
            like your wedding to be, from the cake and flowers, to the head-dresses
            for the flower girls, everything has to be considered and plans put
            into action to make it work. The Marriage Ceremony should also be considered
            as a crucial element in your special day and it too needs
            advance planning so that it goes exactly how you want it.

            <br />

            <br />

            Together, we can design a ceremony that fits the style of your wedding
            and is all about the two of you.  It can be as long or short as you want it.
            You can choose the content. Whether modern or traditional, your wedding ceremony
            should be as unique as you are and together
            we can make one that works perfectly for you both.

            <br />

            <br />

            There are requirements that are integral to the solemnisation
            and registration of a marriage and I will ensure that the process
            runs smoothly and nothing is overlooked. I’m happy to
            explain all of the requirements more fully at our first meeting.

  </div>

            <div id="secondlogo">

                <!-- change according to page -->

                    <img height="100%"
                                                  src="BaseImages/label%20wedding%20client%20testimonials.png"

                    width="100%" />

            </div>

        <div id="secondarytext">

            <!-- change according to page -->

            <div id="second-pic">

              <img height="100%"

                 src="BaseImages/testimonial%20pic%201.png" 

                 width="100%" />

            </div>

        <div id="secondtext2">

            <w>

            Thank you so much for making our day so special.
            The ceremony you planned for us was perfect! 
            It fit in with our theme and reflected our individuality perfectly.

            </w> 

        </div>

        <div id="nekcolpic">

            <img src="BaseImages/testimonial pic 2.png"

            alt=""

            width="100%"

            height="100%" />

        </div>

        <div id="nekcoltxt">

            <w>

            Hi Briony,
            We can’t thank you enough for the time and
            attention to detail you put into our wedding.

            </w>

        </div>

        <div id="nekcolmaintxt">

            <w>

            Your professionalism was outstanding and helped make our wedding day
            run smoothly with everything going off without a hitch.
            Thank you for all the different options you gave us.
            We ended up with exactly the service we wanted,
            even though at the start we had no idea what that was!

            </w>

        </div>

        <div id="secondtext3">

                <w>

                Thanks for all your time and patience and being there
                for us all the way through the process.
                It would not have been the same glorious wedding without you.



                </w>

        </div>

        </div>

        <!-- end #mainContent -->

    </div>

        <br class="clearfloat" />

        <div id="footer">

            <img height="100%"

            src="BaseImages/footer.png"

            width="100%" /> 

        <!-- end #footer -->

        </div>

   <!-- end #container -->
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements positioned with `position: absolute` are positioned relative to the next element up in the hierarchy with `position: relative`, or the screen if you don't have one (which you don't).  The simple fix to your current code is to add `position: relative` onto your main container element:

```
#container {
position: relative;
}
```

This doesn't make your site work completely, but it stops everything moving.  I suspect you'll need to reposition your elements once you've done this, but that might be all you need.

As a general point, you should not be designing for a fixed browser size these days.  It's a simple fact that people don't have the same size screens, and there are many people accessing sites from mobile devices.  If you're not prepared to make your site work on multiple resolutions, then I would recommend starting from some sort of framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) which will allow you to pick and choose their grid elements to achieve your desired layout, without needing to put much effort in to make the site work on other resolutions.

Comment: Legend :) Thank you very much, yes I hated having to use pixels however when I used percentages, IE and Mozilla wouldn't compute with them :( Cheers you fixed it

Comment: If this fixed your problem then you should accept this answer by clicking the Tick.